# Process.Start event needs to be able to pass ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory as a parameter

Tags: .net, vb.net, process.start

I have code that would launch an application using

```
Process.Start(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ApplicationsNameWithPath"))
```

The problem is currently, it seems to require WorkingDirectory path. Since the value currently points to just the Application name, is there anyway to pass exe name and path to config file so that when the above line of code is executed, the workingDirectory is set.

The solution should therefore be the value of the key below

```
<add key ="ApplicationsNameWithPath" value ="C:\Temp\Test.exe"/>
```

Its part of a larger application framework in Production and anyway to just modify 'Value' field in config file to achieve a solution would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot modify your code, then one solution is to create a batch file that sets the current directory and then executes the executable, and then point to this batch file from your configuration file. Here is an example:

In the configuration file:

```
<add key ="ApplicationsNameWithPath" value ="C:\Temp\Test.bat"/>
```

And then create "C:\Temp\Test.bat" with the following content:

```
c:
cd \Test\
Test.exe
```

Don't forget to have an empty line at the end of the batch file so that "Test.exe" will be executed.

If for some reason, you cannot use batch files, then you can create an new executable that would execute your original executable in the correct directory, and then point from the configuration file to such new executable.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using VB.NET there seems to be no other way as to create an instance of the `ProcessStartInfo` class and modify the `WorkingDirectory` like this:

```
Dim processStartInfo As New ProcessStartInfo()

processStartInfo.Filename = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ApplicationsNameWithPath")
processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetFullPath(processStartInfo.Filename)
Process.Start(processStartInfo)
```

In C# there would be the easier way of directly passing an anonymous instance with the property set directly like:

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo( ... ) { WorkingDirectory = ... });
```

**Update: (Thanks Maertin)**

Seems like it is possible to do this in VB (later than 2008) too:

```
Process.Start(New ProcessStartInfo( ... ) With {.WorkingDirectory = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName( ... )})
```

Comment: Thank you for help.  I believe we should be able to pass anonymous instance but somehow I couldn't get syntax working. I was trying that before I posted question since I couldn't get it working. http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?671944-Process-Start-Set-Start-In-Directory